# Smart Client Guidance = Prism? Vs 2010

Tags: c#, prism, smartclient

I have found this link http://smartclient.codeplex.com/  which has some updates for vs 2010 ....

I don't know but i always seem to get confused i.e. lack of documentation etc.....

but is this the same as Prism??

If not can anyone tell me where the differences are...

It appears to be a link for designing smartclient so i presume its composite

Or am i wrong?

If i am indeed wrong, where is the link to prism and the vs 2010 templates?

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prism is kind of the successor to the Smart Client Software Factory. Since Prism is for WPF/Silverlight only, the SCSF still has more of a WinForms focus with some WPF specific extensions.

If you want to build WPF or Silverlight applications, I highly recommend Prism. If you're stuck with WinForms, I guess your only choice regarding p&p guidance is SCSF.

[Prism (aka Composite Application Guidance for WPF) on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648611(v=pandp.10).aspx)

[Prism on CodePlex](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/)